# Optimizing PostgreSQL Performance: Seeking Insights on Automatic Tuning and Best Practices

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, automatic-tuning

I'm exploring PostgreSQL performance optimization. Does PostgreSQL have built-in automatic tuning features or recommended extensions? I've experimented with auto-analyze thresholds and settings, but seek guidance on best practices for optimal performance. Any insights are appreciated!